# angularjs Variable cannot be accessed out side function call

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Recently I started learning AngularJS. My problem is as follows.
I cannot access the data returned by $http.get() out side the method call.

Code :

```
(function(){
    var productApp = angular.module('productApp', []);

    productApp.controller('ProductController', ['$http', function($http){
        var store = this;
        store.products = [];

        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/VeggieFresh/veggie/product/1')
        .success(function(data){
            store.products = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
        console.log(store.products);
    }]);

})();
```

When I print data inside $http.get() method, it could be printed without any problem, but when i try to print it outside method; it displays empty array.

I guess because of this I cannot access this data on HTML as well.
Any help in this regards is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked for me.

```
productApp.controller('ProductController', ['$http', function($http){
        var store = this;
        store.products = [];

        var promise = $http.get('http://localhost:8080/VeggieFresh/veggie/product/1');
        promise.success(function(data){
            store.products = data;
        });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since $http success is a asynchronous call you wont get data immediately outside the function you can call a function for "success" function , or use a callback function

As far as your code is concerned, you can save data on $scope variable

```
  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/VeggieFresh/veggie/product/1')
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.store.products = data;
        //console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The success function runs async, so you will get the result inside success function.